I'm a little confused in namespaces in C++
#include <iostream>

namespace first{
    int x = 1;
}

namespace second{
    int x = 2;
}

int main(){

    int x = 0;
    std::cout << x << std::endl;

    std::cout << first::x << std::endl; 
    
    using namespace second;
    std::cout << x << std::endl; 

    return 0;
} 

This is the code that I was working with. In this code I was expecting 0 1 2 as an output but why am I getting 0 1 0 as the output ?

If x is found in the current scope, the compiler does not bother to look anywhere else. You would need second::x to tell the compiler which x you want.

using namespace second; doesn't remove the current namespace so it's still there and if x is found in that, it'll be used. using namespace second adds second as a fallback to search for stuff in if it can't be found in the current namespace.

using namespace is weird. It doesn't bring the target namespace to the current scope, rather it brings it to the common enclosing namespace of the current and target namespace, which in practice means it gets less priority than normal declarations (except when it causes a conflict with a global-namespace name, which is an error). using second::x behaves more like you'd expect (in your case it causes an error because it conflicts with int x;).

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-directives "Using-directive does not add any names to the declarative region in which it appears (unlike the using-declaration), and thus does not prevent identical names from being declared. "

Summarising the comments above: (1) using namespace second; does not lead to ambiguities for the compiler when choosing the exact reference to x so the compiler does not throw any compilation error, and (2) it does not force the compiler to choose second::x over the variable x in the current scope. To avoid unnecessary complexity, I would recommend you to not use using namespace when possible.

Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that std::endl does. Use '\n' to end a line unless you have a good reason not to.

I would suggest you don't use using namespace to begin with.

Thanks for all your suggestions. My doubt is now cleared

In your code I was expecting 0 1 0 as an output. Why did you expect 0 1 2 as the output? (Maybe you could expand on your question and describe your expectations before giving us code, as suggested in [ask]?)

See this answer in the dupes: using directive and declaration in C++ and for a technical explanation see About the ambiguity of using a name vs using a namespace when doing unqualified calls

I'm just learning C++. Initially I thought that by writing "using namespace second" it would include the value of x within that namespace and then x would become 2 but in the output it was not the case and x remained 0. So that was my doubt.
--- for JaMiT

@Ryujin The main problem here is that a using directive doesn't actually add name to the declarative region. This means that when you wrote using namespace second;, it is as if x were declared in the global namespace. I've explained exactly this in one of the dupes answer: About the ambiguity of using a name vs using a namespace when doing unqualified calls

Because using namespace x only makes x a namespace for so-called "unqualified lookups". It does not, however, make such lookups override local names (so-called "block scope").
Unfortunately, I haven't found a simple list of "what gets searched first" -- but, block scopes or function parameters always shadow the more "global" names.
Think of it as "from inside to outside". You start where your variable name is used, and then move upwards through the scopes until you find the variable. It gets a bit fuzzy when you get to the globals and stuff, but in your example, plain x will immediately hit the function-local variable anyway.
As a side note, I like to specify -Wshadow (g++): it makes the compiler warn when a variable name shadows ("overrides") a more global one. While it can be annoying at times, like when nesting lambda functions that keep taking the same capture, I still find it useful to avoid shadowing so the reader never has to wonder what "version" of a variable is getting used.
For the same reason, I rarely use using namespace, generally opting to be very specific: I will just type second::x or first::x everywhere, so there's never any doubt as to which x is being used at that place.

"Unfortunately, I haven't found a simple list of "what gets searched first" -- but, block scopes or function parameters always shadow the more "global" names.": using namespace finds the name as if it was declared in the narrowest namespace scope that includes both the scope in which the target namespace is declared as well as the scope in which the using namespace declaration appears. I.e. here it would be as if second::x was declared in the global namespace scope.

@user17732522 yes, and now ask a newbie whether he understood that :-) I didn't want to be overly technical on this :-)
